# How can I setup a local environment to work with the latest SameSite cookie change to Chrome?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, security, samesite

I'm building an app with ReactJS and with the latest change to Chrome we're unable to get the cookie back as it's provided by a Central Authentication Service. Granted, in prod it'll have the same domain as the JS app, but for now it is breaking the app locally. I know about `SameSite=None; Secure` but that still needs the third party app (the React app) to access using a secure connection. To me going through those changes locally is overkill.

Is there no other way?

Edit: I have also tried mapping to a domain equal to the auth server in the hosts file but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm passing for the same difficulty. According to what I read/researched there is nothing that can be done.
Who should do this is whoever provides the service/cookie.

A *temporary* solution is to disable the flags **"SameSite by default cookies"** and **"Cookies without SameSite must be secure"**, to do this go to: chrome://flags.

More info: https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/developers-get-ready-for-new.html

Comment: the problem is that the most they can do is set the `SameSite=None; Secure` which doesn't spare you from doing what I mentioned above.