# How can I bypass SameSite cookie restrictions in my development environment?

Tags: security, cookies, cross-domain

Recently, Chrome changed the policy for whether cookies are attached to cross-origin requests. Now, cookies are not attached to cross-origin requests unless:

1. The `SameSite` cookie attribute is either `Lax` or `None` and the request was initiated by a user action, or
2. The `SameSite` cookie attribute is `None` and the `Secure` cookie attribute is `true`, meaning that the cross-origin request has to use the `https` scheme.

(The above is not wrong, but it is slightly simplified. Here is [a more thorough writeup](https://www.troyhunt.com/promiscuous-cookies-and-their-impending-death-via-the-samesite-policy/).)

In my development environment, I use a tool to compile my development language and hot-reload the changes into my browser tab. This tool serves the frontend code on its own port, and the backend is served on a separate port by a separate process, so we're dealing with cross-origin requests from browser to backend. Naturally, both the frontend and backend are served from `localhost` with scheme `http`. And many of the requests that the frontend app makes are not initiated by user action yet still need cookies for auth purposes.

As a result, anything requiring cookies will not work in my development environment. (Yeah, spent quite a while figuring that one out…)

My question is: how can I bypass, work around, or disable these `SameSite` cookie security restrictions for my development environment in an easy way that won't decrease my security as I'm browsing other sites?

It would be nice if, for example, there was a way to add `localhost` to a whitelist of origins in my browser that allowed `SameSite=None` cookies even without a `Secure=true` attribute. Slightly less nice, but still acceptable, would be an easy way to wrap or proxy my `http://localhost:<port>` services so that they can be accessed via the `https` scheme. Or perhaps there's another approach using some obscure cookie magic.

**Update 2021-09-16:** @tommueller points out that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60214817/how-can-i-setup-a-local-environment-to-work-with-the-latest-samesite-cookie-chan) is related. This question is different in that it talks about a [cross origin but] same site situation, where both origins are from localhost.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I setup a local environment to work with the latest SameSite cookie change to Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60214817/how-can-i-setup-a-local-environment-to-work-with-the-latest-samesite-cookie-chan)

Comment: It's definitely related, but not the same. I think the answer by @rowan_m answers my question well but doesn't answer that one well because that question asks about a "central authentication service" (presumably on a different site) whereas my question talks about a same-site situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all of your development environment is hosted under `localhost` then requests between different ports, while cross-origin, still count as same-site. See: https://web.dev/same-site-same-origin/

In your development environment, you can either drop `SameSite=None; Secure` completely or explicitly set `SameSite=Lax`.

Alternatively, look at creating self-signed certificates for `localhost` or local vms to better match your production environment - though that's slightly more involved.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this writing, Firefox does not default `same-site` to `lax` when unspecified, but Chrome does. This flag can be disabled in Chrome here, but warning that this disables the flag for *all* sites you visit, not just your development site.

chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies

Source: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/faq

Comment: This flag has bee removed

Comment: @DerekLawrence you can still set it by a chrome launch option until Chrome 94. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60592944/4742503

Comment: I got around it by adding localhost.domain.ca to my host file to point to my localhost server. Then going to this url "tricks" chrome for the time being as it does give off a warning saying it will be disabled until the future